# Arduino: Getting data from char array

Tags: c++, c, serial-port, arduino, embedded

I just implemented [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) onto my project, so I can transfer data to and from my Arduino setup live.

**The data I get looks like this:**

```
NULL[my_string_send_to_arduino]my_string_send_to_arduino
```

I want the string sent to Arduino, in this case "my_string_send_to_arduino", and only that.

How do I extract this?

**The data comes into Arduino like this:**

```
void ondata(SocketIOClient client, char *data) {
  Serial.println(data);
}
```

So I can't seem to `SubString` it, as it's not a `String` but char. I tried to get it like I would in Javascript, like data[0], to see if the syntax had something to do with an array, but nothing seems to work.

What to do?

Comment: It is not clear what your data look like.  In your description "my_string_send_to_arduino" appears twice (one between [...], and one after that).  It is not clear whether NULL is four capital letter characters of a nul character )`'\0'`.  In short your specification of the received data is ambiguous.  You can indeed index the array (`data[0]`, `data[1]` etc.); your real problem is perhaps why that did not work, and you should perhaps ask about that or at least show what you actually did.  Also what determines the end of the data.

Comment: My data is "my_string_send_to_arduino" and yes, it is outputted twice, that's part of my problem. I just need "my_string_send_to_arduino"...

The Arduino sketch can be found here: https://github.com/billroy/socket.io-arduino-client/blob/master/examples/hello/hello.ino

Comment: You also need to stop assuming that the entire message will be delivered in a single call to your ondata() method.  You have to allow for it being delivered in chunks of various size.

Comment: Oh, really? I didn't know it could do that. Thanks for the heads up.